# Python/Django REST Framework POST based on Content-Type header

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I have an APIView as below and need to 'post' based on the content type header.

We are working with an external PUSH API that needs to post to a single endpoint, firstly JSON data with 'application/json' and then upload a file with 'multipart/form-data'.

The below view works to post one or the other if one is removed ie: just upload file or just post JSON but I can't seem have the view choose to upload the file or post the JSON based on the 'content-type' received with the post.

If there is no file in `request.data['file']` I would like to only post the JSON data and if there is a file then just upload the file. I can post to upload the file but the JSON post serializer expects the 'file' and throws a KeyError.

I have tried various iterations of this code, any ideas how to achieve?

```
class ridesViewSet(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny, )
    queryset = rides.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ridesSerializer
    parser_classes = (JSONParser, MultiPartParser, )

    def post(self, request, format=None):

        up_file = None
        if request.content_type == 'multipart/form-data':
            up_file = request.data['file']

        if up_file == None:
            serializer = ridesSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            if socket.getfqdn() == 'STG' or socket.getfqdn() == 'PRD':
                destination = open(PRD_UPLOAD + up_file.name, 'wb+')
            else:
                destination = open('/Users/ncole/Documents/rides/ridesAPI/uploads/' + up_file.name, 'wb+')
            for chunk in up_file.chunks():
                destination.write(chunk)
                destination.close()
            return Response(up_file.name, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved with the following solution using `if up_file is not None`:

Thank you @RahulGupta for your assistance!

```
# FULL WORKING POST FOR JSON & FILE
def post(self, request, format=None):
    up_file = request.data.get('file')
    serializer = ridesSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        if up_file is not None:
            if socket.getfqdn() == 'STG' or socket.getfqdn() == 'PRD':
                destination = open(PRD_UPLOAD + up_file.name, 'wb+')
            else:
                destination = open('/Users/ncole/Documents/rides/ridesAPI/uploads/' + up_file.name, 'wb+')
            for chunk in up_file.chunks():
                destination.write(chunk)
                destination.close()
            return Response(up_file.name, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
up_file = request.data['file']
```

to

```
up_file = request.data.get('file') # use .get() to avoid keyerror
```

This should prevent the `KeyError` issue.

Comment: Thanks @RahulGupta no KeyError now but getting 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'. Do you know how to get name from request.data.get('file')?

Comment: As you are not using a `FileUploadParser` but a `MultiPartParser`, check for the uploaded file in `request.data` instead looking for the `file` key. It will be populated with a `QueryDict`.

Comment: @ncole458 You can check if file is not `None` in your view as you have done above. Also, don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your issue.